# How can I create a model property with array of strings and a relationship to other model

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, convector

I require some properties in models, like array of strings, and direct relationship to other model

Answer (score 2):

From convector tutorial, extend Person model with

```
export class Attribute extends ConvectorModel<Attribute>{
  ...ommited

  @Validate(yup.array(Attribute.schema()))
  public attributes: Array<Attribute>;

  @Required()
  @Default(['USER'])
  @Validate(yup.array().of(yup.string))
  public roles: Array<String>;

  @Required()
  @Validate(Participant.schema())
  public participant: FlatConvectorModel<Participant>;
}
```

deploy chaincode and invoke with

```
# send USER,ADMIN role
npx hurl invoke person person_create "{\"id\":\"1-100-103\",\"firstname\":\"Pete\",\"lastname\":\"Doe\",\"username\":\"pete\",\"password\":\"12345678\",\"email\":\"pete.doe@example.com\",\"roles\":[\"USER\", \"ADMIN\"]}" -u admin
```

```
# test default role (omiting role)
$ npx hurl invoke person person_create "{\"id\":\"1-100-103\",\"firstname\":\"Pete\",\"lastname\":\"Doe\",\"username\":\"pete\",\"password\":\"12345678\",\"email\":\"pete.doe@example.com\"}" -u admin
```

unescaped data

```
{
  "id": "1-100-103",
  "firstname": "Pete",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "username": "pete",
  "password": "12345678",
  "email": "pete.doe@example.com",
  "roles": [
    "USER",
    "ADMIN"
  ]
}
```

thanks Walter and Diego

done

thanks